# How to convert widememo to string?

Tags: sqlite, delphi

When I use this in Delphi, instead of table name it just shows "(Widememo)". How do I get this to show table name in Delphi 10.4?

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_name, 
   CASE WHEN stat is null THEN 
     0 
   ELSE 
     cast(stat as INT) 
   END AS numrows
FROM sqlite_master m 
LEFT JOIN sqlite_stat1 stat on m.tbl_name = stat.tbl 
WHERE m.type='table' AND m.tbl_name not LIKE 'sqlite_%' 
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: What are you using to execute this query?

Comment: For those who wrote poorly formatted code, it is the exact code I used (wrote) when I googled this. Now @Remy Lebeau, I created a FireDac query and put those lines in the strings of the SQL.  When I put this same code in the SQL editor of the SQL editor window of the SQLiteStudio, it shows each table in one column and the number of records in the second.  However in delphi it shows (WIDEMEMO) in one column and the number of records in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi does not "show". I guess you are using some `TDBGrid` component to see the query result in your application?

The main issue here is that the type of field "tbl_name" is `ftWideMemo` - this means that this field can potentially contain a lot of data, that's why `TDBGrid` does not render this type of field by default.

To fix this, you can do the following:

1. Create design time Fields for this query (they will be created as `TWideMemoField` type).
2. Select this field and change its `DisplayValue` property from `dvClass` to some other value (`dvFull`, for example).

As a result, you will see the real content of this field:

[image: Example]

P.S. Try to make your question clearly, and add all necessary detail, because the direct answer for your current question is "FDQuery1.FieldByName('tbl_name').asString". Hope I guessed what you wanted to ask.